# iOS When press button "next" loading new row form parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I try to create some app, and i have issues, i have structure like this, question, and answers.

My class:

```
class QuestionManager{
 var question: String?
 var answerA: String?
 var answerB: String?
 var answerC: String?
 var answerD: String?

}
```

My Code:

```
var questions = [QuestionManager]()
var arrayIndex = 0
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
query.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) in
if error == nil && objects != nil {
    for object in objects as? [PFObject]{
          self.questions.append(QuestionManager(
          question: object!["question"] as! String,
          answerA: object!["answer1"] as! String,
          answerB: object!["answer2"] as! String,
          answerC: object!["answer3"] as! String,
          answerD: object!["answer4"] as! String

          ))
    }
} else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Using this code i get error:

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(QuestionManager)'

Why i get this, error, maybe you will see my mistake

[image: one more error]

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
var questions = [QuestionManager]()
var arrayIndex = 0
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
query.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) in
if error == nil && objects != nil {
    for object in objects as? [PFObject] {

          let objQuestionManager = QuestionManager()

          objQuestionManager.question = object!["question"] as! String
          objQuestionManager.answerA = object!["answer1"] as! String
          objQuestionManager.answerB = object!["answer2"] as! String
          objQuestionManager.answerC = object!["answer3"] as! String
          objQuestionManager.answerD = object!["answer4"] as! String

          self.questions.append(objQuestionManager)
    }
} else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: now i want go to next question, if i add to arrayIndex +1 nothing not happening

Comment: Above code adds all objects in array. Update your question with how you load next  question.

Comment: i have more the 200 question, when i got 100 question i get error fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: This error not occur from above code, I think this error generates when you load next question.

Answer (score 1):

Add initializer to the class which takes 4 input values.

```
 class QuestionManager{
     var question: String?
     var answerA: String?
     var answerB: String?
     var answerC: String?
     var answerD: String?


    init(quest: String?, ansA: String? , ansB: String? , ansC: String? , ansD: String){
        question = ques
  answerA = ansA
  answerB = ansB
  answerC = ansC
  answerD = ansD


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have not write init() method in your Model class and you are trying to initialize the model class. You can write like this.

```
class QuestionManager{
    var question = ""
    var answerA = ""
    var answerB = ""
    var answerC = ""
    var answerD = ""

    init(question: String, answerA: String, answerB: String, answerC: String, answerD: String){

        self.question = question
        self.answerA = answerA
        self.answerB = answerB
        self.answerC = answerC
        self.answerD = answerD
    }
}
```